# How can I automate recurrent steps in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, automator, google-chrome

I have a set of URLs bookmarked in chrome and I do many times a day:

- Open Chrome
- Open bookmarks
- Search a specific bookmark among my folders
- Click on bookmark

Is there a way to do these actions automatically?

I see that if I press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> the "Spotlight search" searches in my Mail but I can't see how can I create something like what I need.

Do I need to install some other application?

Answer (score 1):

## AppleScript and Automator

AppleScript and Automator are your best starting points for automating OS X. Both are included in OS X, so there is no immediate need to install third party software.

AppleScript and Automator are complementary approaches. An Automator workflow can include AppleScript snippets. An AppleScript can trigger Automator workflows.

See [Introduction to AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html) and [AppleScript: The Language of Automation](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/) for an introduction to AppleScript. You can experiment with AppleScript using the included **Script Editor.app** utility included in your **Applications > Utilities** folder.

Searching the web for `applescript chrome` will return many useful web sites, such as:

- [Scripting Google Chrome for OSX using AppleScript](http://www.xerxesb.com/2010/09/01/scripting-google-chrome-for-osx-using-applescript/)
- [Google Chrome meets AppleScript](http://laclefyoshi.blogspot.fr/2010/10/google-chrome-ver.html)
- [Use AppleScript to open current Safari URL in Google Chrome](http://www.engadget.com/2011/03/14/use-applescript-to-open-current-safari-url-in-google-chrome/)

When you reach the limits of AppleScript and Automator, [third party automation software](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) is available.

Comment: 1) Why would I need to learn a scripting language if there are free third party apps that do this? 2) The software you are linking is not free

Comment: Is it not possible to do this with a free app?

Comment: Not all software is free and not all software will do exactly what you need. Learning a scripting language will allow you to go beyond the capabilities of any individual piece of software. OS X's **AppleScript is free** and an excellent way to combine applications and create workflows.

Comment: I see I can open chrome from the CMD+SPACE. To open it on a specific URL I must use apple script? I am trying to understand what I can or can not do by default

Comment: I'd say Automator is much easier to learn for a beginner, especially if it's just this one job.